# Theme Entity Reference output

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a content type called SimpleNewsletter which has an Entity Reference field called `field_newsletter_content`. Multiple articles are linked with one SimpleNewsletter node.   Under Manage Display of SimpleNewsletter, I can manage which fields to display.

But I have a situation where I only need to display certain fields not all the fields (ex: "Node Title")

In order to theme `field_newsletter_content` field I have created a new file called `field--field_newsletter_content.tpl.php`

Is it possible only to display certain fields?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use the teaser for displaying your entityreference nodes. Under Manage display under format for the entity reference field, choose Rendered entity, choose settings and use teaser instead of full mode.

Go the the display settings for the content type that is being referenced and apply your display settings for the teaser display.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 custom add a new display mode like 'Teaser' or 'Full content with [hook_entity_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7)

Add a view mode

```
  /*   
    * Implements hook_entity_info_alter().  
    */  
    function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {  
      $entity_info['node']['view modes']['NEW_DISPLAY_TYPE'] = array(  
        'label' => t('Title only'),  
        'custom settings' => TRUE,  
      );  
    }
```

Go on
  Structure -> Content type -> Article -> Manage display -> Title only
and set to visible only the title.

Go on
  Structure -> Content type -> SimpleNewsletter -> Manage display
and, in the field_newsletter_content row, select 'Rendered Entity' as Format

Go the the gear on the right and select 'Title only'

Now in your Newsletter node you will have displayed only the title of the connected article

Answer (score 0):

On Manage Display you can on Format select <hidden>.

Comment: example: following fields are part of Manage Display Title, Body and Category... I would like those three fields to be part of the view but in Newsletter only want to display Title... hope this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the module [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to have more control of your display.  Also with display suite you can have more control of  your view modes and layout, if you active field templates that it comes in the display suite extras (not activate it by default) you can even have more control of your css and output. There are some videos that are good...[display suite video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjOG8dVcN4Y). they explain better the power of this module. It is totally worth the time invested in learning this tool.

For your case I think it would really help to use view modes to control the way to render your entity[views modes](http://zugec.com/blog/77-display-suite-part-2-view-modes-and-fields). I hope it helps